# Installing MS Office under Wine

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

I'm having this error: Please insert volume 'OFFICE12' (needed for package 'office2007pro')

Comment: OP is trying to install MS Office under Wine. He is unclear, but the question is tagged as such. OP, all you need is the disk with MS Office.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: @N0rbert: How do you know what OP did to try to install MS Office 2007? Also, please don't put the answer into the question. I took the liberty to revert your unexplainable revision.

Comment: @DavidFoerster No problem. I tried to prevent duplication. So now I asked and answered my [own question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1019952/66509).