# Howto fix "Please insert volume 'OFFICE12' (needed for package 'office2007pro')" on winetricks office2007pro?

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

I'm trying to install MSO 2007 with `winetricks` with the following commands:

```
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.local/share/wineprefixes/office2007pro winecfg
WINEPREFIX=~/.local/share/wineprefixes/office2007pro winetricks office2007pro
```

I get this error message:

> Please insert volume 'OFFICE12' (needed for package 'office2007pro').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved using the following steps:

1. Create iso-file named OFFICE12.iso with label OFFICE12 with your MSO 2007 setup files (folder with *setup.exe* and *autorun.inf*). And then mount it with *Disk Image Mounter* or from terminal. It should mount to */media/$USER/OFFICE12*.
2. Run winetricks again with

   ```
   WINEPREFIX=~/.local/share/wineprefixes/office2007pro winetricks office2007pro
   ```
3. The `setup.exe` will launch. Wait it to finish.

Installation SP3 (*office2007sp3-kb2526086-fullfile-XX-XX.exe*) is recommended too.